# jQuery how to loop through more than 1 sibling element

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, jquery-selectors

I have a jQuery project where I have to loop through a list of h2 headers but in each h2 header I have to loop through their siblings. Each header has more than 1 siblings. Right now I only know how to go to 1 sibling which is using the .next() function. Can someone please help me loop through a list of siblings without changing the direction of my initial code.

```
<script>
// Code Option 1
    function putSiblingsInTableForEachH2() {
        // line above sets function that will ultimately store siblings of each h2.toggler into a HTML table
        var siblingsGoInTable = [];
        // line creates empty array that will hold elements that will eventually go into HTML table
        var togglerHeaders = $("h2.toggler");
        // line above sets variable togglerHeaders to all h2 elements with a class of ".toggler"
        for (i = 0; i < togglerHeaders.length; i++) {
            // line above is a for loop that loops through variable togglerHeaders (for its entire length)
            var currentH2Element = togglerHeaders[i];
            // line above sets variable currentH2Element to togglerHeaders at position i
            // so when i starts at 0 currentH2Element is set to the first element in togglerHeaders which is the first h2.toggler
            for (j = 0; j < currentH2Element.nextAll(); j++) {
                if (currentH2Element.nextAll() !== currentH2Element.val()) {
                    $(siblingsGoInTable).wrapAll("<table></table>");
                } // line ends if statement
            } // line above closes for loop 
        } // line ends for loop
    } // line ends function
    putSiblingsInTableForEachH2();
    // line above actually runs function
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could using [the `.siblings()` method](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) to achieve this.

So, something along these lines might work for you:

```
<script>
    function putSiblingsInTableForEachH2() {
        var siblingsGoInTable = [];

        var togglerHeaders = $("h2.toggler");

        for (var i = 0; i < togglerHeaders.length; i++) {

            var currentH2Element = togglerHeaders[i];

            // Access siblings like this
            var siblings = $(currentH2Element).siblings();

            for (var j = 0; j < siblings.length; j++) {

                var siblingToH2 = siblings[j];
                // Do what you need to do with sibling element here
            }
        }
    }

    putSiblingsInTableForEachH2();

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping. Only thing is when I put in the code I'm getting an error message for this line > var siblings = currentH2Element.siblings();

Comment: It's saying that line is not a function

Comment: Hi @Aishah91 you're welcome - just updated answer. Does this help?

Comment: Yes it does. Thank you. I actually have another question. How do I remove a class from the 1st two elements on this list of h2 tags. I tried many combinations using the .removeClass method but it keeps removing the class from all of them.